# Runtime 440 Excel Error Deleting Selected Row in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

EDIT: So I tried manually performing the actions in this code, and excel also crashed. Does this mean that I've got the same crash error as the other poster?

As a preface, fair warning I am not a professional programmer, I just play with this to try to make my (and my co-workers') lives a little easier.

This code was working a month ago when I made it, maybe it's been broken by an update, not sure, but I'm not sure why it now throws up the error. Another macro I have that's very similar still works.

Now the **macro** throws **Error 440**, and afterwards, MS Excel will crash.

```
Sub RemoveRow()
    Dim Eng As Worksheet
    Dim rmg As Range
    Dim Sup As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

       '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set Eng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Engr+Tech")
    Set Sup = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Suprv+Sppt")

    Eng.Activate

With Eng

    Range("D8").End(xlDown).Select

    '~~> Set your range
    Set rmg = .Rows(ActiveCell.Row)

    '~~> Delete the range
    rmg.Delete

    '~~> Select last row
    Set rmg = .Rows(ActiveCell.Row)
    rmg.Offset(-1).Select

    '~~> Select techs
    Cells(Selection.Row, 4).End(xlDown).Select
    Cells(Selection.Row, 4).End(xlDown).Select

     '~~> Set your range
    Set rmg = .Rows(ActiveCell.Row)

    '~~> Delete the range
    rmg.Delete

    '~~> Select last row
    Set rmg = .Rows(ActiveCell.Row)
    rmg.Offset(-1).Select

    '~~> Select ftechs
    Cells(Selection.Row, 4).End(xlDown).Select
    Cells(Selection.Row, 4).End(xlDown).Select

     '~~> Set your range
    Set rmg = .Rows(ActiveCell.Row)

    '~~> Delete the range
    rmg.Delete

End With

Sup.Activate

With Sup

    Range("D8").End(xlDown).Select

    '~~> Select CLS
    Cells(Selection.Row, 4).End(xlDown).Select
    Cells(Selection.Row, 4).End(xlDown).Select

     '~~> Set your range
     '~~> Set rmg = .Rows(ActiveCell.Row)

    '~~> Delete the range
    .Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Delete

End With

Eng.Activate

Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to tell us exactly where the error is occurring? If unsure, step thru the code until it fails.

Comment: On which line does the error occur ??

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The error is occurring on line 67, the last "delete" action.

Comment: Is there anything unusual about the row that is being deleted - e.g. does it contain information being used by some ActiveX object that you might be using?

Comment: I don't think I have any ActiveX objects. This row is very similar to the ones being deleted on the "Eng" sheet.

Comment: There is a same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455531/error-440-in-visual-basic-application. You can see the answer.

Comment: I'm also worried that this might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/42840134/6535336, in which case there's not a lot that can be done about it except wait for Microsoft.

Comment: D. O. - I tried using the Errorfound code in your link, and it told me:

Source: VBAProject
Desc: Method 'Delete' of object 'Range' failed

Comment: EDIT: So I tried manually performing the actions in this code, and excel also crashed. Does this mean that I've got the same crash error as the other poster?

Comment: What is your Excel version?  I've sometimes been able to resolve wierd issues like this by saving as xlsb instead of xlsm, so you could try that.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I am running Excel 14.0.7177.5000. I went back to a previous version of this sheet from before it even had macros, and it had the same error now.

Answer (score 2):

Try without all of the Select/Activate

```
Sub RemoveRow()

    Dim Eng As Worksheet
    Dim rmg As Range
    Dim Sup As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set Eng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Engr+Tech")
    Set Sup = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Suprv+Sppt")

    '>> avoiding deleting the cell referenced by rmg...
    Set rmg = Eng.Range("D8").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)
    rmg.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete

    Set rmg = rmg.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)
    rmg.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete

    Set rmg = rmg.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)
    rmg.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete

    Sup.Range("D8").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).EntireRow.Delete

    Eng.Activate
    Eng.Range("A1").Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This code, despite being rewritten (much better, by the way), still has the same error in the same spot. It says that method "Delete" for object "Range" failed.

Edit: Line 22 in your code.

Comment: Well it was worth a try.

Comment: Interestingly enough, @TimWilliams, if I move the last delete to the top, it will run correctly the first time. If I then run the macro again, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to everyone that helped me on this one. It turned out to be a security patch from March 17th, and the new patch (released today) corrected the issue.

Here's the update I got:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3178690/ms17-014-description-of-the-security-update-for-excel-2010-march-14-20

Solution was to update to the new patch:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3191855